# Nginx works only on ports other than 80

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have setup Nginx fully and in my config file located `etc/sites-enabled/SITENAME` when `listen` is set to port 1234, 8888, 8080, etc nginx works perfectly. However when setting `listen` to port 80, nginx does not serve pages or even show any errors. I just get timeout errors instead.

I am using `ufw`. My `ufw` settings look like:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
1234                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
1234 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I have checked for other proccesses using port 80, there is none apart from Nginx.

Other info that may be helpful:

- I am using nginx in a virtual environment
- I am not on root user account, instead I am on a restricted user account in the sudo group so I can use sudo commands
- I have not edited any other Nginx config files.

Thanks for the help!